Как убрать "моргание" текста при отрисовке компонента?
У меня есть компонент у которого имеется условная отрисовка, что-то наподобие этого:
<div>
{isTrue ? <h1>True</h1> : <h1>False</h1>}
</div>

При этом значение isTrue зависит от запроса на сервер при помощи RTK Query, а изначально равен false что-то наподобие этого:
let isTrue = false;
isTrue = useGetIsTrue().data;

При этом при отрисовке компонента у меня промигивает текст False, а True отрисовывается через несколько миллисекунд. Как можно исправить данные промигивания?

Зависит от реализации useGetIsTrue.

@eri Там простой get запрос на сервер

Не простой, а асинхронный

Прям в лоб это не "поправить". Можно, допустим сделать задержку в 200-400мс после вызова запроса и держать false, потом уже применять true(если ответ пришел). Можно вместо false вывести какой то плейсхолдел или пустоту(не отображать ничего при false)

@SwaD да почему же. Если в лоб, то добавить await или перенести установку значения в done callback.

@eri ну так до установки значения там будет false. Начинается то все с false и вопрос как раз в этом, убрать "моргание" которое вызвано задержкой между первым рендером и получнием данных. Либо ничего не рисовать, либо подменять данные как то, либо сгладить смену увеличением времени ожидания

useGetIsTrue().data что тут будет до завершения гет запроса?
